# How to scale multiple objects in Blender 2.82+ without a plugin

Tags: objects, transforms

Blender 2.82+ question. Imagine you have 3 cubes. You want them scaled to exactly 42% on the X axis. I cannot find a way to do this without a plugin.

I mean not scaling by dragging the scale handles, but scale using value input.
What I end up is that I get only one object scale, the rest do not change.

EDITED.
Apologies, seems I've posted the question strangely truncated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the scaling mode from 'Median point' to 'individual origins'.

Scaling three spheres 3 increments on the x axis with the default - 'median point'.
[image]

Scaling three spheres 3 increments with transform settings set to *individual origins*.
[image]

What this does is allow the objects simultaneously selected to scale around their own origins instead of the active selected object. (The one highlighted in yellow).

To scale the objects "42%", go to select mode (the default when you open blender), select all of the objects, make sure you have the transform mode set to individual origins, and press <kbd>S</kbd> then press <kbd>X</kbd>. Type in '.420' to set the scale to 42%. You do not need to be in transform or scaling mode in object mode to scale an object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's very useful !  
My mistake while posting - my question got truncated. I've edited it, so now the meaning is slightly more understandable :)
Can you have one more look at it, please?

Comment: What surprises me is that when I scale using the transform handles all 3 objects sale together. But when I use the Transform value input only one of the objects is scaled.

Comment: I guess your problem is solved then. I hope my answer helped with that.

Comment: Maybe our hotkeys are different? Or Blender version?
When I press G I enter "grab" mode. When I press X I seem to constrain move to the X axis.
I'm not sure how to switch to scale or where to type .420 - but even in move mode only one of the objects seems to be affected.

Comment: Ok, I think I've got it. After pressing G I need to select S for scale or R for rotation, then the axis - X,Y,X.

Thank you!

Comment: Oop Sorry! My mistake! I meant to write S not G!